# how to apply lowercase in char_filter?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to apply the lowercase to the char filter.
I used pattern_replace, but it doesn't work.

```
"custom_lowercase": {
    "type": "pattern_replace",
    "pattern": "([A-Z])(.*)",
    "replacement": "\L$0"
}
```

How can I apply the lowercase in the char_filter?

Comment: You can simply add "filter": [ "lowercase" ] to your analyzer

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the customized version to lowercase the tokens, in the analysis chain of Elasticsearch analyzer, token-filter comes last, hence using the in built [lowercase token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html#analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter) will convert all the tokens to lowercase.

one example of lowercase with custom analyzer shown in [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html#analysis-custom-analyzer)

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom", 
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to apply the lowercase before tokenize not after. The reason is that i want to make sure that tokens defined by the user dictionary are recognized as the same token regardless of lower/uppercase.    
ex) **now** 
user_dict: sm5,
sm5 -> sm5,
SM5 -> sm, 5  
    
**what i want**
user_dict: sm5,
sm5 -> sm5,
SM5 -> sm5,

Comment: @gwkim I don't think its possible, were u able to find out a way?